# Elastic Grok Pattern Netscaler example?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, netscaler

I am lost ! I have an example netscaler log and I want to use Grok Pattern in elastic.

Example Log:

```
Dec 18 20:37:08 <local0.info> 10.217.31.247 CEF:0|Citrix|NetScaler|NS10.0|APPFW|APPFW_STARTURL|6|src=10.217.253.78 spt=53743 method=GET request=http://vpx247.example.net/FFC/login.html msg=Disallow Illegal URL. cn1=233 cn2=205 cs1=profile1 cs2=PPE0 cs3=AjSZM26h2M+xL809pON6C8joebUA000 cs4=ALERT cs5=2012 act=blocked
```

I dont know the pattern for <local0.info>
The timestamp is: %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp}, thats easy, but what about the next one and the other strings ?

I really hope someone can help me out :S

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to debug the grok patterns. Below is the GROK pattern for your example log:

```java
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} \<%{DATA:data}\.%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\> %{IP:ip} %{DATA:data}\|src\=%{IP:source_ip} %{GREEDYDATA:payload}
```

Let's split the field **payload** using [KV Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-value_split) of the logstash.

```java
kv {
           source => "payload"
           value_split => "="
           field_split => " "
           target => "msg"
         }
```